# Getting pdf document from envelop

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am working on a project that requires integration of digital signature so for this i am using DocuSign API. So when i try to get pdf document from envelop I get following response:

"[INFO] Written 120184 byte to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\713F.tmp. Please move the file to a proper folder or delete the temp file after processing"

Here is the code:

```
 $envelop_api = new EnvelopesApi($this->getApiClient());
            $singed_pdf = $envelop_api->getDocument(session('accountId'), session('envelop_id'), "1");
```

I want to store incoming file to my own directory so far this is not happening, 
Please help me to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP, right?
you can use the `copy()` method after you download
you can use the `sys_get_temp_dir()` to find the temp file path
Just copy it from the temp file to your own file, no need to even delete the temp file.